# Bottom to top <ul> element arrangement

Tags: html, css, positioning, html-lists

I'm trying to find out how I can force  elements to start from the bottom going to the top.

I have searched through stackoverflow and I can't seem to get the answer that i need.
This picture should explain it:

[image: explanation image]

This should help too:

```
<?php require("connectdb.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Dynamic Drag'n Drop</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.ui.ipad.altfix.js"></script>


<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#contentWrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 2px #EEEEEE;
}

#contentTop {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#sortable li { margin: 20px 20px 1px 20px; 
padding: 1px;
 float: left; 
 width: 70px; 
 height: 70px; 
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center; 
 background-color:#cfcfcf;
 position: absoute;
 bottom: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 }


#contentRight {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#336600;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#save
{    
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#336600;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
.on { background-color:#000000; color:#782322; }

            #header{
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                font-weight: bold;
                width: 804px;
                margin-left: auto ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                padding: 2;
            }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
//$(document).ready(function(){ 



    $(function() {

    $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);  

        $("#sortable").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function()     {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") +     '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
            $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        }).addTouch();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

        //$("li").click(function(){
            //$(this).addClass("on");
        //});   
    });

//});   
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        session_start();
        $teacherID = $_SESSION['teacherID'];
        $classID = $_SESSION['csID'];
        $qryClass = "SELECT * FROM class_schedule WHERE csID = '". $classID ."';";
        $class = mysql_query($qryClass);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($class))
        {
            $subjCode = $row['subjCode'];
            $section = $row['section'];
            $semester = $row['semester'];
            $sy = $row['SY'];
            $time = $row['time'];
        }
    ?>
    <div id = "header">
        <?php 
            //echo "What do you want to do, " .$fname . "?<br>";
            echo "Subject: " . $subjCode . " Block: " . $section . " -     Semester:" . $semester . " - SY:" . $sy . " - " . $time;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrap">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <?php
                session_start();
                $query  = "SELECT e.*, CONCAT(s.lname,', ', s.fname) name     FROM enrollment e, student s
WHERE e.studentID = s.studentID AND e.csID = '". $classID ."' ORDER BY sort;";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $c = 0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {
                    //if($c != 4)
                        echo "<li id='recordsArray_'"     . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
                }
                ?>
            </ul>       

    </div>
    <div id="save">
        Blackboard
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'm pretty sure its not possible. Why can't you insert the elements in reverse order? (without changing the order in the html)

Comment: You should always include the relevant code within your question.  This way if the file/page you are linking to ceases to exist, your question will still remain and could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: My bad, I was having problems with inserting the code. But yeah, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks, James Montagne.

Comment: @Oliver Ah, it's cuz I need the elements to be in that order. What I'm working on is actually about a class attendance checking site. The bottom part is the first row and the top part is the second row. I need to simulate it as to how the teacher will view it when he/she is in front of the class and checking the attendance seats.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A css solution [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/7GUCx/)

```
ul, ul li {
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
   -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
     -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);

}
ul {
    width: 350px;
}
 li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    zoom: 1;         
    *display: inline;
}
```

This works by flipping the entire `UL` and then each `LI` on it's Y axis.

Comment: my li elements went missing after I added the transform code to the ul. When I only apply it to LI, the text elements are reversed :D

Comment: WOW... interesting, great idea. How would IE or older browser with no `css transformations` render this though?

Comment: @alpaca lips nao hey bro, i seem to have made it work by applying it on the div holding my ul instead of on the ul instead! I dunno but I hope my question and this answer gets archived so that other users in the future may use this.

Comment: @user1056998: I believe the `LI` went missing due to the `float: right`, but I see you found a workaround. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: @Maroshii: IE versions >9 will ignore the `transform` property and render it as a typical `UL`.

Comment: You just saved my butt from failing my senior project, thank you so much @alpacalipsnao

Comment: @alpacalips--nice solution. I added one that accomodates older browsers.

Comment: ingenious solution to this problem. This worked really well with my chat application

Answer (score 2):

### For Older Browsers (IE7+)

***It can still be done***, assuming a limited set of objects as the css will get more complex for more rows (though not impossible). For the original six objects in the problem, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqLCn/11/). For 12 objects in 3 rows [see another](http://jsfiddle.net/AqLCn/45/).

Note: I realize some version of an `:nth-child()` selector could be used rather than the cumbersome code below, but then it would again not be supported by older browsers (which was my point in adding my answer to this post).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    width: 210px;
}

li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

li:first-child,
li:first-child + li,
li:first-child + li + li,
li:first-child + li + li + li {
    margin: 51px 0 -99px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change $query to the following. That would be the easiest way to do it.

```
$query  = "SELECT e.*, CONCAT(s.lname,', ', s.fname) name     FROM enrollment e, student s
WHERE e.studentID = s.studentID AND e.csID = '". $classID ."' ORDER BY sort DESC;";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think so. That will only rearrange the values inside the boxes but not the arrangement of the boxes.